# How to export a web page in excel

Tags: java, spring, jfreechart

I am using spring mvc and I have a web page which contains a html table with data and a Jfree chart based on the data , now my problem is how to export the entire page in an excel file with same look and feel.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );
} );
```

TableTools is a plug-in for the DataTables HTML table enhancer, which adds a highly customisable button toolbar to a DataTable. Key features include:

Copy to clipboard
Save table data as CSV, XLS or PDF files
Print view for clean printing
Row selection options
Easy use predefined buttons
Simple customisation of buttons
Well defined API for advanced control

refer [Jquery DataTables Table Tools plugin.](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

Answer (score 0):

As Far as I know you can't just take a JFreeChart graph and turn it to excel 'with the same look and feel' as you write.
So there are 2 possible approaches here:
1. You take a JFreeChart output, turn it into image and with the help of Apache POI add this image to Excel
2. You don't use JFreeChart at all, instead you work only with Apache POI APIs, create Excel sheet with data and let the Excel generate your graphs.

Of course you can combine these 2 solutions as you wish.
Hope this helps